# What's Swift current time Date object precision when it is initiated using the default constructor?

Tags: swift

What's the current time Date object time precision when it is initiated using `Date()`? Does it capture the time to milliseconds?

```
let currentTime = Date()
print(currentTime) // 2022-10-09 09:13:39 +0000
```

When I print the date it only shows `2022-10-09 09:13:39 +0000` so I wonder if its precision is only to the second.

Comment: You can try `let date1 = Date.now print(date1 == Date.now)` in a playground :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does it capture the time to milliseconds?

Yes, it does. `print`ing a date shows a fixed string description omitting the fractional seconds. A hint is that `TimeInterval` is defined as a floating point type (`Double`).

You can prove it

```
let interval = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
print(interval)
```

which shows a **real** fractional part rather than a [*Is-floating-point-math-broken*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) value like `.00000003`

Comment: This answer is only accurate when close enough to 2000. Millisecond precision will be lost at astronomic scale.